# Disable submit action in input text

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, submit

I have a problem with an input text area since if I press enter key the page refresh and I don't want this. I read many tutorials and similar questions but nothing works for me.
I past my angularjs code:

```
$scope.startEditMode = function(className,index) {
    $scope.editMode = true;
    console.log($scope.editMode);
    var td = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.value=td[index].innerHTML;
    td[index].appendChild(input);
    td[index].innerHTML='';
    input.setAttribute("onSubmit","console.log('ciaaa')");
    td[index].appendChild(input);

    console.log(index);
}
```

This method is called when I clicked twice on a cell of my table to edit its content.

Here is my html table code:

```
<div class="tablewrap" id="display">
                        <div class="tablewrap-inner">
                            <div>
                                <table class="table  table-hover" border="1">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="check"><input type="checkbox" onchange="checkAll(this)" ng-click="checkAllTrue()"/></th>
                                            <th class="descrPosHeader">Descrizione posizione&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('name')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                                            <th class="numPosHeader">Numero posizione&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('numPos')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                                            <th class="fattHeader">Fatturazione&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('fatt')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                                            <th class="impUnitHeader">Importo unitario&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('impUnit')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                                            <th class="quantHeader">Quantità unitaria&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('quant')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                                            <th class="impRataHeader">Importo rata&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('impRata')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                                            <th class="numRateHeader">Numero rate&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('numRate')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>                                        

                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr id="lista" ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:sortingOrder:reverse ">
                                            <td class="check"><input id="selectLine1" type="checkbox" value="{{item.check}}" ng-click="item.check=!item.check"/></td>
                                            <td class="descrPos" ng-dblclick="startEditMode('descrPos',$index)">{{item.name}}</td>                                            
                                            <td class="numPos" ng-dblclick="startEditMode('numPos',$index)">{{item.numPos}}</td>
                                            <td class="fatt" ng-dblclick="startEditMode('fatt',$index)">{{item.fatt}}</td>
                                            <td class="impUnit" ng-dblclick="startEditMode('impUnit',$index)">{{item.impUnit | euro}}</td>
                                            <td class="quant" ng-dblclick="startEditMode('quant',$index)">{{item.quant}}</td>
                                            <td class="impRata" ng-dblclick="startEditMode('impRata',$index)">{{item.impRata | euro}}</td>
                                            <td class="numRate" ng-dblclick="startEditMode('numRate',$index)">{{item.numRate}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

What do you suggest?

Comment: @DarkSkull is whole HTML is wrapped inside form ?

Comment: nono that's only the table... the rest of the code in visualforce and it's not important

Comment: Is there a submit button in the page?

Comment: No I create in a dynamic way an input text